# Как сделать css анимацию адаптивной по ширине?

Tags: css, вёрстка, css3, адаптивная-верстка, css-animation

Код на codepen - codepen.io/Andrey-m/pen/QjypPV?editors=110

Пытаюсь освоить анимацию css

Помогите поправить код, чтобы сохранить адаптивность.

У меня при уменьшении окна по ширине все рушится.

Условно "полоса загрузки" задана в px, ставлю % результат не тот, который ожидается

Конечный результат предсказуем.

Подскажите ошибки.

Если кто-то сможет поправить код - вы святой человек, большое вам спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

У вас проблема в неправильном проектировании. Анимационный блок должен быть резиновым и все элементы должны быть асолютно спозиционированы внутри него в процентах. Так чтобы этот блок можно было кинуть внутрь любого контейнера и получить результат.

Вот пример:
http://jsfiddle.net/IonDen/ssgx0j7w/

HTML:

```
<div class="anim">
    <div class="anim-point num--1">
        <div class="anim-circle">1<div class="anim-done"></div></div>
    </div>

    <div class="anim-point num--2">
        <div class="anim-circle">2<div class="anim-done"></div></div>
    </div>

    <div class="anim-point num--3">
        <div class="anim-circle">3<div class="anim-done"></div></div>
    </div>

    <div class="anim-point num--4">
        <div class="anim-circle">4<div class="anim-done"></div></div>
    </div>

    <div class="anim-point num--5">
        <div class="anim-circle">5<div class="anim-done"></div></div>
    </div>

    <div class="anim-pol"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.anim {
    position: relative;
    background: #eee;
    height: 30px;
}

.anim-point {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.anim-point.num--1 {left: 0%;}
.anim-point.num--2 {left: 25%;}
.anim-point.num--3 {left: 50%;}
.anim-point.num--4 {left: 75%;}
.anim-point.num--5 {left: 100%;}

.anim-circle {
    position: absolute;
    top: -30px;
    left: -30px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 58px;
}

.anim-done {
    position: absolute;
    top: -40px; left: 1px;
    width: 58px; height: 58px;
    background: #00f;
    border-radius: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
}

.num--1 .anim-done {
    animation: DONE-1 5s infinite;
}
.num--2 .anim-done {
    animation: DONE-2 5s infinite;
}
.num--3 .anim-done {
    animation: DONE-3 5s infinite;
}
.num--4 .anim-done {
    animation: DONE-4 5s infinite;
}
.num--5 .anim-done {
    animation: DONE-5 5s infinite;
}


@keyframes DONE-1 {
    0%   { opacity: 0; top: -40px; }
    10%  { opacity: 0.8; top: 1px; }
    100% { opacity: 0.8; top: 1px; }
}

@keyframes DONE-2 {
    0%   { opacity: 0; top: -40px; }
    20%  { opacity: 0; top: -40px; }
    30%  { opacity: 0.8; top: 1px; }
    100% { opacity: 0.8; top: 1px; }
}

@keyframes DONE-3 {
    0%   { opacity: 0; top: -40px; }
    45%  { opacity: 0; top: -40px; }
    55%  { opacity: 0.8; top: 1px; }
    100% { opacity: 0.8; top: 1px; }
}

@keyframes DONE-4 {
    0%   { opacity: 0; top: -40px; }
    70%  { opacity: 0; top: -40px; }
    80%  { opacity: 0.8; top: 1px; }
    100% { opacity: 0.8; top: 1px; }
}

@keyframes DONE-5 {
    0%    { opacity: 0; top: -40px; }
    90%   { opacity: 0; top: -40px; }
    100%  { opacity: 0.8; top: 1px; }
}



.anim-pol {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    background: #f00;

    animation: BAR 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes BAR {
    0%   { width: 0; }

    20%  { width: 25%; }
    25%  { width: 25%; }

    45%  { width: 50%; }
    50%  { width: 50%; }

    70%  { width: 75%; }
    75%  { width: 75%; }

    100% { width: 100%; }
}
```